# Switch with red LED to lower left of steering wheel

Tags: chevrolet, truck, silverado, dashboard, switches

What is the purpose of this button with a red LED light (to lower left of the steering wheel) on my 2010 Silverado 1500?

[image]

Comment: Does the red light turn on when you switch it? If the light turns on, what happens? That switch does not come on the Silverado, so someone added it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 No, the red light doesn't turn on when I switch it. Nothing happens, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

There is no telling what the purpose of this switch is used for. **It is not a stock switch and didn't come on the Silverado from the factory**. Someone installed it for some purpose other than what was designed into the truck from the get go. Since the light does not come on when you toggle it, you can have a pretty good assumption the switch is not energized. To figure out what it was supposed to do, the best you can do is trace wires coming from the switch.